# Laravel 5 slow refresh waiting for blocked storage access requests from trackers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cookies

I've moved a laravel app form a domain to another. All works well but I noticed, after clicked on subitting a button, that it spend 20seconds to refresh the paige. During this the system is waiting for an external components (addthis.com, google ads etc..), end when solved the process in console I read the "Blocked: Storage access requests from trackers" message.
I've setup session.php to 'same_site' => 'lax' (it was null..) but nothing happends.
Do you have some idea?
How to include safe url list as walk-artoud it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi after this change you should clear the cache of config laravel
on your console you write :

```
php artisan config:clear
```

to permit accept the changes and then clear the cache of your application with

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I was tried with `php artisan optimize:clear` with no results, but as you suggest it works right, thank you a lot!
Have I  repeat this periodically or only if I update session.php?